# C++ generate random graphs suitable for TSP

Tags: c++, random, graph

I'm testing various TSP models/algorithms. Right now I'm using a full adjacency matrix, filled with random values from 1 to 100, which represents a complete directed graph.

I'm searching for a more rigorous approach that would allow me to try different kinds of random graphs, like Erdos-Renyi, small world networks and scale free networks.

I know I may have to switch to adjacency lists for the new graphs.

My approach would be generating a random graph and then ensuring there is the Hamiltonian path necessary for the problem to be a valid TSP instance. Is it possible, or is it cheaper to just try and solve the unsolvable instance (assuming all methods will terminate on such instance)?

BTW I was thinking of using the Boost Graph Library, but I'm not familiar with it, and maybe there's something more appropriate. Suggestions for alternatives are welcome, but should not be considered the main scope of this question.

I don't need a TSP solver, I need something to aid in the generation of acceptable problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a monotone gray code, a.k.a a hilbert curve. It can help find a hamiltonian path:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code.

Comment: Interesting. Care to add some details? There's just a small paragraph on Wikipedia talking about the Hamiltonian path.

Comment: @Agostino:Why is your graph directed?

Comment: Because it represents an asymmetric TSP. I also intend to solve the symmetric variant. I'm looking for graph generators and a way to recognize which graphs represent solvable instances.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm searching for a more rigorous approach that would allow me to try
>   different kinds of random graphs,

Check Mathematica. It has a built-in predicate to test whether a given graph has hamiltonian path or not. It also, has a predicate to generate random Hamiltonian Graphs.

In addition, If you have not try it yet, [TSBLIB](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/) contains (hard and easy) instances that you may find them useful.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an option. I'm searching free solutions that pure C++ (or at least callable from it). Mine is a learning project, so using a TSP solver would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @Agostino I thought you are trying to test different algorithms not to generate random instances. Seems I was mistaken.

Comment: I'm generating the random instances to test the algorithms, and I want to do it in C++ (my own code+libraries+solvers).